# AmazonS3Exception occurs accessing S3FileInfo properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to access Amazon S3 file properties such as "Exists", "Length", "LastWriteTime", etc...with AWS .NET SDK in VS2010.

I am getting a list of files within a directory using:

```
S3DirectoryInfo directory = new S3DirectoryInfo(client, bucket, key);
            S3FileInfo[] fileList = directory.GetFiles();
```

fileList is now an array of S3FileInfo objects.  However, when I look at the object, all of the file properties have an exception listed, instead of the property.  The exception is an AmazonS3Exception, Forbidden 404 from the server.  I can do the same thing with a directory listing and get the properties for directories, but file properties are always forbidden.  Just in case the issue was with the `directory.GetFiles()` method, I also tried to creating a single S3FileInfo using:
    `S3FileInfo fileInfo = new S3FileInfo(client, bucket, key;`

The results are the same.  I know the client, bucket and key are fine, as I use them for all sorts of other operations with success, it just S3FileInfo that is having issues.

I am running a MVC 2 web application, in Visual Studio 2010, running version 2.3.18.0 of the AWS .NET SDK, with Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: Can you share your bucket policy and IAM role?

Comment: I have not set a bucket policy or IAM role yet.  I have created a single IAM User that has a single access key and secret access key that I use. (I am using S3 in a dev environment only at the moment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem.  I went into the AWS IAM Console, Users.  I selected the User I wanted, and under Permissions I selected "Attach User Policy". I used the Administrator Access Policy Template.  That fixed my problem.  Thanks Vor for sending me down the path of looking at my policies and roles.  The strange thing is that I could use the .NET SDK to add AWS users, create S3 buckets, keys, upload/download files, set encryption etc...The only thing I couldn't do was access file properties.
Very strange, and my guess is it is a bug or at least not intended.  Seems strange to disallow viewing file properties without Administrative Access, while I could do virtually anything else.